# PayPal checkout - credit card tab by default

Tags: paypal, checkout

Is there anyway to make that the part where you enter your credit card information is open by default, instead of the part where you enter your paypal information?

I really need this, but wasn`t able to find anywhere!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only way to do that is with [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#ec).  In your [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) request you set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing.

This will force the full credit card form to be displayed so people can enter a credit card without creating a PayPal account...

[image]

This can't be done with [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#wps), unfortunately.  "Guest Checkout" is available with Payments Standard, but it's all cookie based, so if any person on the computer being used has ever signed in to a PayPal account it will assume that's what they'll be doing in the future and it won't present the credit card option.

**EDIT**

This question came up again and I had more information to provide.  [Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799030/paypal-expresscheckout-api-behavior-changed-recently).

Comment: excellent - this information is worth it's weight in gold if that makes sense :p

Comment: Well, unfortunately, PayPal is changing things so this doesn't work anymore.  They're rolling out new EC experience pages and they've removed the full credit card option even when setting these parameters.  Very frustrating, but it doesn't look like they're going to be changing it back.  There's a chance you're still on the old pages, which would still do this, but as soon as your account gets updated to the new pages this functionality will go away, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, just realized while implementing that, my thanks still holds nevertheless. Will be posting the updated solution once I implement it - on a sidenote the new express checkout offers much more exciting flexibility.

Comment: Even with a verified business account, a PayPal pdf May 2012 ["Preparing for the New Updated PayPal Checkout Experience"](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/) indicates that there's something like A/B testing going on. My experience early 2014 seems to indicate the old UI still sometimes shows up. (That we can default to the new section title of "Pay with a debit or credit card".) And, I can't find a way to auto-force the "Checkout as a Guest" button, which is what I'd definitely like to do.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, they have been making some changes and seem to be steering away from this option.  Myself and many others have voiced our opinions about that on their partner channels. We'll see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

for people reaching here from google and still cant manage to solve it , there are several key factors to this :

1. PayPal parameters: if you look at [PayPal's API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) there are 3 relevant fields: LANDINGPAGE, USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE, SOLUTIONTYPE .
2. Not sending email parameter. change email parameter to '' (blank) . if you do send email parameter it will always open the login tab.
3. Cookies. no matter what you do , if the user have a PayPal cookie on his browser , the login tab will open by default (and the above parameters will be ignored) there is no solution for that (as far as I know) so make sure you check if it works with a cookie virgin browser.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you working on the latest implementation of Express Checkouts, all you need to do to have the credit card tab open by default is add an extra `&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US`(or any country code for the matter as default) to the nvpstring before doing a `SetExpressCheckout` and it will begin working like a wonder.

Cheers :)

Comment: This has not worked in any of my tests.  The new pages are still being split, though, so it's possible the time this was attempted it just happened to use the old layout.