# Paypal ExpressCheckout API behavior changed recently

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

In an existing implementation of Paypal Express Checkout API, we had the landing page set to a credit card entry page by setting the flags:

`SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole`,
`LANDINGPAGE=Billing`,

and everything worked the way we wanted.

As of today, this is not longer working. If the customer has a paypal account cookie set, they get this login with no way bypass the "paypal login" and enter a credit card directly

[image]

If they don't have a paypal cookie set, then they are at least given a "guest checkout" option:

[image]

the complaints we get are that customers can't remember their login credentials, and dont' want to go through the lost password procedure. They just want to give us money, and we just want to take it.

Is there anyway to give them a Guest Checkout option, even if they have a paypal cookie set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the new landing pages they also introduced a new parameter.

> USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE
>
> (Optional) This element could be used to specify the preferred funding
>   option for a guest user. However, the LANDINGPAGE element must also be
>   set to Billing. Otherwise, it is ignored.
>
> - BML – Bill Me Later
> - ChinaUnionPay
> - CreditCard
> - ELV

So keep your current parameters the way they are and add this new parameter to SetExpressCheckout set to CreditCard and you should get the old flow like you're wanting.

You also need to make sure you're using API Version 109.0 or higher because this new parameter was introduced in version 109.0.

Comment: I added the `USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard`, and the `LANDINGPAGE=Billing` and it still behaves the same.  I read the [paypal api documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: The classic NVP API I linked to in my previous response. This one [https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: That's not what I meant.  I meant the actual version value that you're passing into the VERSION parameter in your API request.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. `$version = urlencode('98.0')`

Comment: Try updating that to 112.0

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Accepted answers and points are appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I have the same problem and I use 112. It worked 2 month ago but PayPal changed the behavior! With the Sandbox it works!

Comment: My guess is that you're just seeing the new version of the page.  Can you provide a screenshot of the page you get when redirected to PayPal?

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="Billing">
```

This works as of Sep 2016

Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.