# Paypal Express "pay with credit or debit card" option

Tags: paypal

I have two different systems set up to use Paypal Express, both use the same account.

On system A after the customer is directed to the Paypal website, they have two options, 1 to log into their account, the other to "pay with a credit or debit card". See picture

[image: system a - pay with credit or debit card]

On system B at the same stage the customer doesn't have this option.

Does anybody know what the setting or config item to control this is? As said we've got different integrations connected to the same account so I don't think it's a setting in the Paypal account its self.

Comment: Check [this question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891261/paypal-checkout-credit-card-tab-by-default/13895911), as well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799030/paypal-expresscheckout-api-behavior-changed-recently) which stemmed from the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express checkout was originally designed to compliment a merchant's existing credit card options with the option to pay with PayPal by logging into their account. By default the feature in question doesn't exist. An additional parameter must be sent to PayPal with the SetEC call: SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole. If you are using a 3rd party shopping cart it's possible the cart doesn't support the feature.

Comment: in my case SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole but still its not working