# PayPal Express Checkout API - is there a way to make the credit card form default?

Tags: paypal

I am using the Express Checkout API by PayPal and the link generated is like:

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXXXXX&useraction=commit#/checkout/login`

The default page shown is like this:

[image]

Is there any way to make it so that the credit card form is the default one? It may be a bit confusing to first time PayPal shoppers.

I tried `&SOLUTIONTYPE=SOLE` as suggested in other topics but that didn't change anything.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Express checkout is set up to favor PayPal. You can use [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) to customize the payment experience but accept PayPal as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please append a new parameter

```
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

That means which type of PayPal page to display.

1. Billing – Non-PayPal account
2. Login – PayPal account login

Please check Reference URLs for paypal express checkout behavior.

[PayPal checkout - credit card tab by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891261/paypal-checkout-credit-card-tab-by-default)
[Paypal ExpressCheckout API behavior changed recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799030/paypal-expresscheckout-api-behavior-changed-recently)
[SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)