# Paypal Checkout is Opening on [Pay with a debit or credit card, or PayPal Credit] tab

Tags: magento, paypal

Guys we are configuring paypal checkout for magento.
And problem we now facing that by default it opens on [Pay with a debit or credit card, or PayPal Credit] tab
http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/952/6024581916.png

Which API parameter/setting determines that?

How to make it open on [Pay with my PayPal account] tab by default, so visitor don't have to switch(make extra step).

Comment: checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891261/paypal-checkout-credit-card-tab-by-default

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Magento provides a simple setting to adjust this, but the SetExpressCheckout request has a parameter that let's you control that.

- LANDINGPAGE=Login - This would make the PayPal login the default.  This is also the default action if the LANDINGPAGE parameter is left out of the request altogether or has no value.  A value of Billing for this parameter would default to what you're seeing now.

It seems odd that Magento would be defaulting to Billing, but I'm not seeing any settings specifically for that.  The only thing I do see is the "Enable PayPal Guest Checkout" option, which if enabled, could very well be setting the LANDINGPAGE parameter to Billing.  You can try disabling that and see if you get the login by default.