# Paypal modify checkout UI

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

Before asking my question I would like to inform readers that I have searched, I have googled and have tried my best but can not find an answer to what should be something simple, perhaps I just miss read the info...but here goes.

The following link on paypal express checkout UI modification

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVnQO.png): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/ shows how you can modify the checkout user interface to the following:

[image]

However I can not find an explination in the official docs on where to start or how to approach this modification...Has anyone done this before? Any tips will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straight forward, pass the customer info through - it's highly unlikely the debit/credit area will be expanded:

After the call to SetExpressCheckout, the buyer is redirected to the PayPal. On the Choose a way to pay page, buyers having a PayPal account can log in with their email address and password. Buyers who do not have an account can use their debit or credit card to pay and will have their shipping and contact information filled out.

```
[requiredSecurityParameters] 
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout 
&RETURNURL=https://...
&CANCELURL=https://...
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=1 Main Street
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=San Jose
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=CA
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=95131
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL=jsmith01@example.com
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=408-559-5948
```

Although knowing Paypal they would not have the debit/credit card section expanded by default because they want customers to use Paypal.

Comment: `Seems pretty straight forward, pass the customer info through` I get that but does that mean in doing so the UI will automatically change? I dont care about the shipping address since im selling a digital product...Im after the expandable debit/credit card section as you might have guessed

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891261/paypal-checkout-credit-card-tab-by-default looks like a no for now because paypal recently changed the checkout screen, which I'm not surprised Paypal would try to force customers to use a Paypal first