# PayPal Checkout - Open credit card tab by default

Tags: php, paypal

I wanted to serve my visitors with Credit Card payment tab on PayPal Checkout by default rather than PayPal login. I tried [this stackoverlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891261/paypal-checkout-credit-card-tab-by-default) but of no avail. Could someone please let me know if that's possible? If yes, how please?

Comment: Need to see a sample of the request you're sending to PayPal.

Comment: SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing is correct or it could be a setting on your business account.. you would need to talk to paypal about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this new parameter to SetExpressCheckout set to CreditCard and you should get the flow like you're wanting:

`USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard`

along with:

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole,
LANDINGPAGE=Billing,
```

You also need to make sure you're using `API Version 109.0` or higher because this new parameter was introduced in `version 109.0.`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked. In case of cookie set in the browser, it still opens PayPal checkout rather than credit card. But I think that's the way.

Comment: @user3104307, I am glad it helped. Yes in case of cookie set in the browser, it would open PayPal checkout.